# Error while using count

Tags: vba, excel

I have an sheet "Result" and I am trying to count the number of "Green", "red" and "" values in the column "K" of my sheet. I am then printing this value In my sheet "status". in  sheet status I have a table with column A as week number. So if the weeks in the column A of sheet "status" is the same as the weeknumber in sheet "result" of column O, then I start counting for the values in column K

I have the code working, But I am lost, due to somereason, the count value I receive is not the correct one. For eg "green" I have 73 rows with green in column K of result. but I could see it printed in my sheet "status" as 71.

Could anyone help to figure what is going wrong ?

```
Sub result()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim cntu As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim totalrows As Long
Set sht = Sheets("Status")
Sheets("Result").Select
totalrows = Range("E5").End(xlDown).Row
n = Worksheets("Result").Range("E5:E" & totalrows).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.Count(sht.Columns(1))
cntT = 0
cntu = 0
cntS = 0
If sht.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "WW")) Then Exit For
Next i
 For j = 5 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(17))
 If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("Q" & j) And Range("K" & j) = "Green" Then cntT = cntT + 1
 If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("Q" & j) And Range("K" & j) = "Red" Then cntu = cntu + 1
 If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("Q" & j) And Range("F" & j) = "" Then cntS = cntS + 1
If cntT <> 0 Then sht.Range("C" & i) = cntT
If cntu <> 0 Then sht.Range("D" & i) = cntu
If cntS <> 0 Then sht.Range("B" & i) = cntS
If n <> 0 Then sht.Range("G" & i) = n
Next j
If cntR + cntu <> 0 Then
'sht.Range("D" & i) = cntR / cntu * 100
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend using a formula for this. Look into `CountIf`

Comment: What is in your column 17, a function? Is it possible that the result of `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(17))` might change due to the action taken by the macro? Try assigning that value to a variable before the For ... Next loop so that you can be sure nothing is counted twice.

Comment: @Variatus my column 17 has the weeknumber.

Comment: @Variatus column 17 does not change by the macro

Answer (score 1):

I worked my way through your code and found a irregularities in your loops. Your variables I and j seem to be counting both rows and valid rows. Therefore I renamed these variables to make clear that they are rows. Also, your code tests each row for Red, Green and "". I think it can only be one of these. Therefore, if one is a match the other two can't be. This can lead to double counting. Finally, I found that you seem to be writing the final result to the Status sheet, in the same cells, many, many times.

I'm sorry, the following code isn't tested because I have no data. But I have tried to address the above problems.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyResult()          ' "Result" is a word reserved for the use of  VBA

    Dim cntT As Integer, cntU As Integer, cntS As Integer
    Dim WsStatus As Worksheet, WsResult As Worksheet
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim Rs As Integer, Rr As Long               ' RowCounters: Status & Result
    Dim n As Integer

    Set WsStatus = Sheets("Status")
    Set WsResult = Sheets("Result")
    TotalRows = Range("E5").End(xlDown).Row
    n = WsResult.Range("E5:E" & TotalRows).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
'   Improper counting: Rs is not necessarily aligned with the row number:
'    For Rs = 2 To WorksheetFunction.Count(WsStatus.Columns(1))

    For Rs = 2 To TotalRows
        If WsStatus.Cells(Rs, "A").Value = Val(Format(Now, "WW")) Then Exit For
'        If WsStatus.Range("A" & Rs) = Val(Format(Now, "WW")) Then Exit For
    Next Rs

'   Improper counting: Rr is not necessarily aligned with the row number:
'     For Rr = 5 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(17))

    With WsStatus
        For Rr = 5 To TotalRows
            If (.Cells(Rs, "A").Value = .Cells(Rs, "Q").Value) Then
                If (.Cells(Rs, "K").Value = "Green") Then
                    cntT = cntT + 1
                ElseIf (.Cells(Rs, "K").Value = "Red") Then
                    cntU = cntU + 1
                Else
                     If (.Cells(Rs, "A").Value = "") Then cntS = cntS + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next Rr
    End With

    With WsResult.Rows(Rs)
        ' it would be better to write even 0 to these cells
        ' if you don't want to show 0, format the cell to hide zeroes
        .Cells(2).Value = IIf(cntS, cntS, "")       ' 2 = B
        .Cells(3).Value = IIf(cntT, cntT, "")       ' 3 = C
        .Cells(4).Value = IIf(cntU, cntU, "")       ' 4 = D
        .Cells(7).Value = IIf(n, n, "")             ' 7 = G
    End With
    '    If cntR + cntU <> 0 Then                   ' cntR isn't defined
        'WsStatus.Range("D" & Rs) = cntR / cntu * 100
    End If
End Sub
```

I urge you to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your sheet and declare every variable you use.

Comment: Thank you for the effort and feedback.  sure I will comment, If there is any problem. Also, will upvote it,if it is correct